# Can't change the name of the downloaded file in DownloadManager class dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

i'm using the Download Manager class to download Mp3 files .

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
//dls is an arraylist that holds the download links
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(dls.get(0));
                DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"file.mp3");
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

the `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` method requires a second parameter that will change the name of the downloaded file .

I want the file to have its default name . If i dont use the method the file will have its default name but it wont be located in the Download directory .

How can i achieve both , locate the file in the Download directory and leave the name of the file as it is ?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
public static String getFileNameFromURL(String url) {
if (url == null) {
    return "";
}
try {
    URL resource = new URL(url);
    String host = resource.getHost();
    if (host.length() > 0 && url.endsWith(host)) {
        // handle ...example.com
        return "";
    }
}
catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    return "";  
}

int startIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
int length = url.length();

// find end index for ?
int lastQMPos = url.lastIndexOf('?');
if (lastQMPos == -1) {
    lastQMPos = length; 
}

    // find end index for #
    int lastHashPos = url.lastIndexOf('#');
    if (lastHashPos == -1) {
    lastHashPos = length;   
    }

    // calculate the end index
     int endIndex = Math.min(lastQMPos, lastHashPos);
    return url.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

This method can handle these type of input:

```
Input: "null" Output: ""
Input: "" Output: ""
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html" Output: "test.html"
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html?id=902" Output: "test.html"
Input: "file:///home/user/test.html#footer" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com" Output: ""
Input: "http://www.example.com" Output: ""
Input: "http://www.example.txt" Output: ""
Input: "http://example.com/" Output: ""
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html?param=value" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html#anchor" Output: "test.html"
Input: "http://example.com/a/b/c/test.html#anchor?param=value" Output: "test.html"
```

You can find the whole source code here: https://ideone.com/uFWxTL

Comment: this method wont work unfortunately . Because the download link does not contain any information about the file name.